# jOOQ Function generation of UNSIGNED BIGINT generates LONG rather than ULONG

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq, unsigned-integer

I have a SQL (MySQL) function defined as:

```
FUNCTION `ifs_getPrimaryAddress`(aEntityId BIGINT unsigned, aTable VARCHAR(25), aResultType VARCHAR(10)) RETURNS varchar(500)
```

Note the **UNSIGNED** bigint argument.  When I generate the jOOQ, it creates the argument as a Long rather than a ULong:

```
public static Field<String> ifsGetprimaryaddress( Field<Long> aentityid, Field<String> atable, Field<String> aresulttype ) {...}

public void setAentityid(Field<Long> field) {
    setField(AENTITYID, field);
}
```

Shouldn't it generate as a **ULong**?   I've modified the code manually to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug (https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5202) in jOOQ 3.7.3.

The current code generator implementation picks up the "unsigned" type specification only for table columns.

Comment: Thanks again for the awesome support and rapid response!